# Sanitize array using array_map

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

I am trying to [`array_map`](https://php.net/array-map) to sanitize an array, which I have created from a csv file. Here's my code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['csv']['size'])) {
    if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0 && $_FILES['csv']['size'] != NULL  ) { 
        //Clear existing qty_csv table
        mysqli_query($conn,'TRUNCATE TABLE qty_csv');
        $row_count  = 0;
        //get the csv file 
        $filename = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']; 
        $handle = fopen($filename,"r"); 
        $delimiter = ',';
    $unescapedArray = array();
        $data = csv_to_array($filename,$delimiter);

function array_map_callback($a)
{
  global $conn;
  return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $a);
}

$data2 = array_map('array_map_callback',$data);
```

Whenever I run my bit of code I get the warning:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

This is the structure of the original data:

```
part_code varchar(20)
part_descr varchar(255)
part_location varchar(20)
part_qty_in_stock int(11)
reorder_level int(11)
reorder_qty int(11)
part_price decimal(6,2)
```

Comment: Globals and mysqli_real_escape_string. If you're already using mysqli, why not just prepare and execute your statements?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean as I am a reluctant convert to mysqli

Comment: You are already using mysqli. And to insert csv data, preparing once and executing over and over is more efficient and safer too. Can you edit your queries into your question, maybe we can help you convert it into prepared and executed statements.

Comment: I have put in the queries as you requested, if that is what you meant.

Comment: can you show a relevant part of your `$data` structure? this because you say (in answer comment) that `$data` is single-dimensional array, but this is incompatible with error reported above.

Comment: I have inserted the structure of the data

Comment: @geoff What is the content of $data?

Comment: I got the code you put up and inserted it into my code. I got the following 'Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload_csv.php on line 90' and when I sent this comment a minute  your code disappeared, apologies. I am unfamiliar  with that code structure.

Comment: The code I inserted was: `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO qty_csv(code, descr, location, qty_in_stock, reorder_level, reorder_qty, price) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');

$stmt->bind_param('isiiid', $part_code , $part_descr, $part_location, $part_qty_in_stock, $reorder_level, $reorder_qty, $part_price );

foreach ($data as $arr) {
    list($part_code , $part_descr, $part_location, $part_qty_in_stock, $reorder_level, $reorder_qty, $part_price ) = $arr;

    $stmt->execute();}` and I got the error:

Comment: Why aren't you using `fgetcsv()`?

Comment: I added `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "$username", "$password", "$database");
` and that removed the error. $miken32 I will have a look at fgetcsv. Never used it before. Does it eliminate the need to look for apostrophes? It is midnight here so will say g'night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what people in the comments were talking about with prepared statements. The statement is [pre-loaded with `?` placeholders](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), and then each of the placeholders is [bound to a variable](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

So [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) gives us each line of the file in an array element which we can easily loop through with `foreach`. Within the loop, we use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to turn each CSV line into an array (though if you prefer to roll your own, be my guest) and [execute the prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php).

Every time the statement is executed, the bound variable value is checked and placed into the statement. The overhead of setting up the database is only done once, resulting in a lot less overhead. Plus you get the bonus of not needing to escape strings; MySQL does it for you.

Of course for production code you'd want to include checks to make sure statement preparation, variable binding, and execution don't throw any errors. Also you didn't include a CSV sample, so you may have to allow for any non-standard separators or terminators in `str_getcsv()`.

```
//assuming you have up here something like this:
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbase);

if (!empty($_FILES['csv']['size'])) {
    //Clear existing qty_csv table
    $conn->query('TRUNCATE TABLE qty_csv');
    //get the csv file 
    $filename = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
    $data = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $row_count  = count($data);
    //value has to exist for bind_param to work
    $csv = str_getcsv($data[0]);
    $query = "INSERT INTO table (part_code, part_descr, part_location, part_qty_in_stock, reorder_level, reorder_qty, part_price) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssiiid", $csv[0], $csv[1], $csv[2], $csv[3], $csv[4], $csv[5], $csv[6]);
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $csv = str_getcsv($row);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually did have the fgetcsv() in a function i was calling 'csv_to_array'. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by an item in $data which is not a string. Do a var_dump to see what's inside the $data before passing it to array map. Or you could do something like:

```
function array_map_callback($a)
{
    global $conn;
    if (is_array($a) {
         foreach($a as $idx => $item) {
            $a[$idx] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $item)
         }
         return $a;
     } else {
         return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $a);
    }
}
```

But this is just a possible solution, it may be better to find out why you have  a non-string in your $data array, and make sure it doesn't get there.

Comment: $data is an array of a number of fields, some of which are strings and some are numeric. I guess I will have to break it down further into the actual string fields I want to test.

Comment: Not sure how mysqli_real_escape_string behaves with an int. Can you check if passing something numeric like `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 1234)` give an warning. If yes, you can skip numeric values similarly checking with`is_numeric($a) { return $a }`.

Comment: You had a typo in the `foreach` which I fixed, you were trying to escape `$a` which would result in exactly the same error! Also, here's a tip: `foreach` can do things by reference. Comes in handy often. `foreach ($a as &$item) $item = mysqli_real_escape_string($item);`